# check if key exist in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to check whether a specific key in NSUserDefault exists. The problem is that it keep returning error. How come it returns `lldb` error?

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("teams") as? NSData {

}
```

Comment: Your example works ok. It checks for the value and not the key, indeed, but it shouldn't bring the debugger.

Comment: Good chance you have a manual break point set.

Answer (score 7):

This code works for me. Try it :

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") != nil) {
     // perform your task here
}
```

Comment: Ever stored "nil" in NSUserDefaults? It usually just removes the whole thing.

Comment: @EricD. Checking if the value is `nil` is the only way to check. Since you can't store `nil` in `NSUserDefaults`, if the key exists, you will get back a non-nil result for the key's value. If you get `nil` for the value, then the key doesn't exist.

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't realize that earlier. Thank you for explaining in detail.